Husband turns wife's murderer into woman and falls in love with him
So as the title suggests I think this is a Spanish or French film (but I could be wrong about both) where someone murdered a woman and her husband who is a doctor captures him, sedates him and then operates on him to make him look just like his wife. They then fall in love.
It was definitely out between 2008 and 2011, can't remember any actors they were strangers to me. Please help!

Pretty sure I know what you're after, but more details would really help: Approximate year, possible actors, specific scenes etc. Do you remember anything else?

It was definitely out between 2008 and 2011, can't remember any actors they were strangers to me. All I remember is the doctor kidnapping the murderer and turning him into a woman that looks like his wife and then they fall in love

You're looking for Pedro Almodovar's The Skin I Live In from 2011.

A brilliant plastic surgeon, haunted by past tragedies, creates a type of synthetic skin that withstands any kind of damage. His guinea pig: a mysterious and volatile woman who holds the key to his obsession.

The surgeon (played by Antonio Banderas) has turned the young man who was indirectly responsible for his daughter's death into the spitting image of his late wife. Here's the trailer:




BTW, if you're wondering why the other answer sounds so close, it's because both movies were inspired by the same novel.

Oh wow... this is it thanks :s It's creepy to have found it so easily, couldn't remember Banderas in this :S Just some spanish haha THANKS! :)

I believe the movie you're looking for is Victim (2010).  It's not a Spanish or French film but it somewhat fits the description of what you're looking for.  

A young man finds himself held captive by a mysterious Doctor and his British henchman.  Performing a sex change to replace the doctors daughter who has recently been murdered. 





Hm no, the plot is very similar indeed but the first victim is the doctor's wife (for that I am sure) not his daughter. But thanks this is also a good suggestion!
